# How to pass name of form_for's method to partial in rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views

Good day! Little newbee question:
let's say I want to generate fields of form_for helper of special appearance. Thus to not to repeat complex code to generate many fields of model, I render some partial and pass there parameters. There is a reference to form object amongst them. 
Question is what pass to render method to call in the partial necessary method of form object? For example I want to generate this time email_field:

```
<%= form_for @order do |f| %>
<%= render :partial => 'form_field_special', :locals => {:form => f, :type => :email_field, :labelcaption => "SpcName"} %>
<% end %>
```

and partial itself:

```
<div class="control-group">
<%= f.label :name, <%= labelcaption %> , :class => "control-label" %>
<div class="controls">
<%= f.type :name %> # ??????
</div>
</div>
```

thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ruby power. [Object#send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Object.html#method-i-send) method:

```
<%= form_for @order do |f| %>
  <%= render :partial => 'form_field_special', :locals => {..., :field_type => 'email_field'} %>
<% end %>

<%= f.send(field_type, :name) %>
```

Comment: thank you! though I've already solved this problem, and your solution one may consider as an option for mine

Answer (score 0):

The following method proved as the fastest way to invoke ruby object's function by its name:

```
m = form.method(name_of_the_method)
m.call(parameters)
```